# How to get Chanel Name by giving Youtube ID

Tags: json, api, youtube, youtube-api

I need to get chanel name, and coutn views of a youtube video..

I use Youtube API, and i want to send the argument : video code

And result , the views coutn of that video, and the channel name (not chanel id)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer here: [How to get YouTube channel name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806944/how-to-get-youtube-channel-name)

It stated that you can extract the video id from the URL, and then make an HTTP GET request: `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dQw4w9WgXcQ?v=2&alt=json` where `dQw4w9WgXcQ` is the video id you're interested in.  This returns a JSON response, with the channel name in the `author` field.

For the count views of a YouTube video, you can use the [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports).

> Video reports provide statistics for all user activity related to a channel's videos or a content owner's videos. For example, these reports contain the number of views that your videos received. In the YouTube Analytics API, some content owner video reports also include estimated revenue and ad performance metrics.

Here's a related thread: [How to count the total number of views from a youtube channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566343/how-to-count-the-total-number-of-views-from-a-youtube-channel)

Comment: This is only working url for me ----"https://www.youtube.com/channel/youtube_channel_id"